# Vue.js append multiple classes

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I'm trying to append multiple classes when the user clicks on a item i have this this:

```
<div :class="[ item === form.score ? 'text-black bg-white': '' ]"
    @click="form.score = item"
    v-for="item in 10">
   {{ item }}
</div>
```

But it does only append the `bg-white`. Is there a better way?

Comment: only append `bg-white`, are you sure? open your **browser inspector** to double check it.

Comment: If you are only using that string with two classes you should use the object syntax. `:class="{ 'text-black bg-white': item === form.score }"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in multiple ways:

```
:class="[ item === form.score ? 'text-black': '', item === form.score ? 'bg-white': '']"
```

or

```
:class="[ 'text-black': item === form.score, 'bg-white': item === form.score ]"
```

or

```
:class="[ 'text-black bg-white': item === form.score]"
```

[more info](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`:class="{ 'text-black': is_item(item), 'bg-white': is_item(item) }"`

and in your methods:

```
is_item(item) {
 return this.form.score === item
}
```

or even better

`:class="classes(item)"`

and in your methods:

```
classes(item) {
 return form.score === item ? ['text-black', 'bg-white'] : ''
}
```